# Testing RDBMS and O.S

Tags: java, windows, database, linux, unix

I am in the process of testing a variety of RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and FirebirdSQL) using a Java application to do so, this is for personal interest and partly for research at university. I have opened a question regarding the database side of things i.e. what tests would be appropriate to conclude performance differences.

This question relates to the Client O.S and the RDBMS Server O.S.

I am unsure if there will be a large difference between the results when running the Java Application on differing opperating systems and the RDBMS on different Servers.

My Question is would you agree that Windows 7, Ubuntu Desktop 10.10 and Oracle Solaris would reuslt in a fair Client side comparison. With Ubuntu Server and Windows 2008 fair server side comparison?

Would you agree that I should also include a Unix based server to house the RDBMS?

Thankyou to everyone who takes the time to give input.

Answer (score 0):

Typical Server OS includes: Ubuntu/Debain/RedHat Server and other linux flavors, windows 2008, Solaris and AIX

And it will be sufficient to test Client on OS like: windows xp/7, Mac OS X, Ubuntu. Also be careful while selecting the flavor/implementation of client JRE/JVM and the version.